# How can I use Collate and a equivalent of SQL Server "Replace" function at the same time in EF Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Entity "produtos", a entity "index".
The entity "produtos" has a list of "index", which are keywords related to that product for search. It's a many to many relationship.
I'm using the bellow code to make the search and it works, but I need to implement a equivalent of the SQL Server "Replace" function so that the query ignores a specific character ("-") in the search and returns records with or without them. For example if I search for TRex it will return TRex and T-Rex, and if I search for T-Rex, it will also return TRex and T-Rex.

The generated SQL:

```
SELECT aLotaStuff
FROM (
    SELECT OtherLottaStuff
    FROM [Produtos] AS [p]
    WHERE (([p].[EhKit] = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (([p].[ValorUnitario] > @__p_0) AND ([p].[ValorUnitario] < @__p_1))) AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [ProdutoIndice] AS [p0]
        INNER JOIN [Indice] AS [i] ON [p0].[IndiceId] = [i].[Id]
        WHERE ([p].[Id] = [p0].[ProdutosId]) AND ([i].[PalavraChave] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = @__Replace_3))
    ORDER BY [p].[Id]
    OFFSET @__p_4 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_5 ROWS ONLY
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [c].[CategoriasId], [c].[ProdutosId], [c0].[Id], [c0].[CategoriaPaiId], [c0].[GomecCategoriaId], [c0].[GomecCategoriaPaiId], [c0].[Nome], [c0].[Url]
    FROM [CategoriaProduto] AS [c]
    INNER JOIN [Categorias] AS [c0] ON [c].[CategoriasId] = [c0].[Id]
) AS [t0] ON [t].[Id] = [t0].[ProdutosId]
LEFT JOIN [FotosProdutos] AS [f] ON [t].[Id] = [f].[ProdutoId]
ORDER BY [t].[Id], [t0].[CategoriasId], [t0].[ProdutosId], [t0].[Id]
```

```
            var produtos = _dbContext.Produtos.AsQueryable();
            produtos = produtos.Where(x => x.EhKit == true).Where(x => x.ValorUnitario > valMin && x.ValorUnitario < valMax);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
            {
                var searchTerms = searchTerm.Split(' ');
                foreach (var term in searchTerms)
                {
                    if (term.Length > 1 && term !="de")
                    {
                        //produtos = produtos.Where(p=>p.Indice.Any(ind=>ind.PalavraChave == term));
                        produtos = produtos.Where(p => p.Indice.Any(ind => EF.Functions.Collate(ind.PalavraChave, "Latin1_General_CI_AI") == term));
                    }
                }
       
     }
```

I tried a stored procedure, but it got complicated to call it, because I need the equivalent to "AND" (I need results with each one of the strings in the search split by space

Comment: Why not just `EF.Functions.Collate(ind.PalavraChave.Replace("-", ""), "Latin1_General_CI_AI")`

Comment: @Charlieface
Because it will not return the results with the "-". For example, If I search for "TRex", I want the results "T-Rex" and "TRex".

Comment: What is the generated SQL for that? Maybe the `-` isn't really a `-` maybe it's a different character? Can you copy/paste it *exactly* from SSMS into here?

Comment: @Charlieface , that query works. The problem is how to implement the funcionality to ignore the "-" sign. I made a query in SQL server using the Replace method and it worked. The question is how to implement that method in EF core

Comment: @Charlieface, I'm sorry. It's just too long to fit in here, but the "-" is really a "-". That's not the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Charlieface I edited with the SQL

Comment: Could be wrong, but it looks like you did `EF.Functions.Collate(ind.PalavraChave, "Latin1_General_CI_AI") == term.Replace("-", "")` rather than what I suggested `EF.Functions.Collate(ind.PalavraChave.Replace("-", ""), "Latin1_General_CI_AI") == term` although maybe that's actually what you wanted, it's not clear

Comment: @Charlieface  I did as you sugested before. It didn't return any rows

Comment: @Charlieface, it worked with 2 replaces:
                     string searchTermWithoutHyphen = term.Replace("-", "");
                        produtos = produtos.Where(p => p.Indice.Any(ind =>
                        EF.Functions.Collate(ind.PalavraChave.Replace("-", ""), "Latin1_General_CI_AI") == searchTermWithoutHyphen));
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realize both the search term *and* the values had `-` in them

Answer (score 0):

For those who face the same issue when making a search mechanism, here is the answer:

`string searchTermWithoutHyphen = term.Replace("-", ""); produtos = produtos.Where(p => p.Indice.Any(ind => EF.Functions.Collate(ind.PalavraChave.Replace("-", ""), "Latin1_General_CI_AI") == searchTermWithoutHyphen));`